# Category ID returns as '0'?

Tags: loop, categories

I'm trying to populate the category id from the category name within the loop.

```
    <?php $cat_name = get_theme_mod( 'cat_1' ); ?>
    <?php $category_id = get_cat_ID($cat_name); ?>
    <?php query_posts('cat='.$category_id); ?>
```

the cat_1 theme mod is a category dropdown I have in the theme customizer that gets and lists category names in a dropdown list. Currently, my loop is showing all posts from all categories instead of the category selected from theme_mod cat_1.

When I use:

```
    <h4><?php echo $category_id; ?></h4>
```

it returns as '0' instead of the id of the category when selected from the category dropdown (theme mod cat_1).

Answer (score 1):

Answered my own question, although not exactly how I had originally intended.

```
    <?php 
        $cat_name = get_theme_mod( 'cat_1' );
        $cat_name = str_replace(' ','-',$cat_name);
    ?>
    <?php query_posts('category_name=' . $cat_name); ?>
```

So instead of trying to convert the category name to the category id, this seems to convert the category name to the category slug.
I can test this by echoing $cat_name and it returns the category slug and not the category name.

In any case, this works now. Posted so others can use it if they need it.

Comment: Just one note, you should never ever use `query_posts`. It is an evil way of running queries as it breaks the main query and slows page load times

Comment: Source? What would be a better alternative?

Comment: pre_get_posts, WP_Query, or  get_posts. See this question's accepted answer for a good explanation of when to use each of the available alternatives: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts